# Graph of Dirichlet Kernel with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing a document in maths and I want to add the graph of the Dirichlet Kernel. The graph is what seems in the picture:

[image]

I'm trying to use tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7,yscale=0.95]
\node at (3.9,-0.2) {$x$};
\draw [thick, ->] (-5.25,0) -- (5.25,0);
\draw [thick, ->] (0,-0.6) -- (0,5.5);
\draw [ultra thick,blue,domain=-5:5] plot (\x, {(sin((4+0.5)*\x r))/(sin(0.5*\x r))});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I have this result.

[image]

Could someone help me to make it better?

Comment: Add even some more samples points with `samples=200` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As vi pa already pointed out in the comments, taking more samples solves your problem. Meaning, you just have to add `samples=200` as an argument to your last draw command and the graph will be smooth. KersouMan's hint of adding the `smooth`-option only worked to a limited degree when I tried it. Indeed pdftex generated a PDF with a smooth plot, but it threw an error saying `Dimension too large` nonetheless. Hence, I'd recommend using vi pa's suggestion that doesn't throw an error (at least for me). Here is the corrected code as an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7,yscale=0.95]
\node at (3.9,-0.2) {$x$};
\draw [thick, ->] (-5.25,0) -- (5.25,0);
\draw [thick, ->] (0,-0.6) -- (0,5.5);
\draw [ultra thick,blue,domain=-5:5,samples=200] plot (\x, {(sin((4+0.5)*\x r))/(sin(0.5*\x r))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you are working with tikz, I can generally recommend the official documentation. It's very extensive and has a huge amount of examples. Depending on your TeX-distribution, you should be able to open it by executing `texdoc pgf` on the command line. Otherwise, it's available on [CTAN](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

With `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=88mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style = {->},
    axis on top,
    trig format=rad,
    xmin=-4.5,  xmax=4.5,
    xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt},
    xlabel={$x$},   x label style={anchor=west},
    ymin=-3,  ymax=9,
    ylabel={$y$},   y label style={anchor=south},
    domain=-4:4, samples=150
            ]
\addplot [ultra thick,blue!70] {(sin(4*x))/(sin(0.5*x))};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]